# Appying filter to requests from a huge JSON data

Tags: python, json, api, flask, request

I want to retrieve data from an api, which has following format:

```
{
...

"grapthData": [
    [
      1592298900000,
      2063.95
    ],
    [
      1592298901000,
      2060.2
    ],
    [
      1592298902000,
      2057.05
    ],
    [
      1592298903000,
      2059.5
    ],
    [
      1592298904000,
      2058.75
    ],
    [
      1592298905000,
      2057.7
    ]
...

}
```

Now there are countless elements in "grapthData", which represents a second in epoch, now I only want the indexes which marks completion of a minute.

How to set filter for the same while making a request to api with Flask?

Comment: You can use `json.loads` to load Json to nested `list`s and `dict`s. -- "I only want the indexes which marks completion of a minute" what determines when this is true? You can use a list comprehension to filter out unwanted values.

Comment: @ninMonkey I need to skip the next 60 values for beginning the count to the next minute

Comment: @ninMonkey this is to be done after I get the response right? My problem is that I'm not even getting the response back, maybe because of the data is too big.

Comment: right, that was for after the response. To simplify things, (without flask) see if your request is working using the [requests module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). Check what http status code your response is returning a failed response could be any of -- [1] bad url [2] wrong get|post type [3] invalid api call [4] invalid data [5] not authenticated --

Comment: @ninMonkey it hasn't return anything right now since last 3 mins when I ran the app, the page is still loading, while the url is correct